# How do I Apply checkbox reset to only one sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox

I am trying to use the below script to automatically change checkboxes to false.
It works fine but....
I now need to apply this ONLY to the sheet titled 'TASKS', and not to any others within the spreadhsheet.

Can anyone assist?
image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cUzh.jpg

***this is also my first ever javascript attempt.
previous to this, i did some myspace tamporing 15 - 20 years ago

Comment: current string: 

 function resetCheckboxes(){
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheets = sh.getSheets();
  for (let i in sheets){
    sheets[i].getRange('B1:B11').setValue(false);
  }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this modified script bring your expected result?

#### Modified script:

```js
function resetCheckboxes() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  const sheet = sh.getSheetByName("TASKS");
  const range = sheet.getRange('B1:B11');
  range.uncheck();

  // or sh.getSheetByName("TASKS").getRange('B1:B11').uncheck();
}
```

- When this script is run, the checkboxes of "B1:B11" of "TASKS" sheet are unchecked.
- In this case, in order to retrieve the specific sheet, `getSheetByName` of Class Spreadsheet is used.
- In order to uncheck the checkbox, `uncheck()` of Class Range can be used.

#### References:

- [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)
- [uncheck()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#uncheck)

Comment: That was perfect, Thank you.

This was my first attempt at any scripting (except MySpace back in the day)